# Synchronous Scrolling across sheets (tabs) in a Google Sheets Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scroll, synchronous

I am new to Google Sheets, Apps Scripts and JavaScript so kindly bare with me.

I am particularly interested in Google Sheets due to its ability to control user access to specific ranges for data entry purposes.

I have information that I would like split across different sheets in a spreadsheet. As there is a lot of information with details that can be categorized, I am planning to separate the information across different sheets/tabs per category for ease of use.

Due to the expected large number of rows, I wanted to be able to synchronously scroll across these category sheets also for ease of use. I managed to do the same using Macros on Excel, [please see this excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NVzra9WILi0e5GI1AelCt3TTndB3ptxL/view?usp=sharing) to have an idea of what I am intending to do.

Basically when a cell (or even row) is selected in the active category sheets, the same row is selected in all the other inactive category sheets. Alternatively, when the user selects a category sheet, it should check which row is selected in the previously selected category sheet and select the same row in the newly active sheet.

I was playing with Apps Script but wasn't able to set the selection of an inactive sheet. Similarly, when selecting another category sheet, I was unable to get the selected range from the previously selected category sheet - getSelection() and getActiveRange() always return selection of the current active sheet.

Is there any way I can achieve this? Are there alternative solutions anyone can suggest to reach a similar target? For example I was also looking at the sidebar but that reduces the number of columns viewable ... wanted to minimize horizontal scrolling as that is the main intention of splitting the data between sheets to begin with.

I will greatly appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to programmatically scroll all sheets to the same row as the active range.

If that's the case, you can just look through all sheets and set the corresponding row (using the `rowIndex` from the active range) as the active range, using [Sheet.setActiveRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setActiveRange(Range)), as shown here:

```
function scrollAllSheets() {
  const rowIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const row = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    sheet.setActiveRange(row);
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  });
}
```

If you want the script to run when a new cell is clicked, use an [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger. For that, just change your function name to `onSelectionChange` and, optionally, use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) (argument `e`):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const rowIndex = e.range.getRow();
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const row = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    sheet.setActiveRange(row);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- I don't think it's necessary, but in order to make sure the spreadsheet selection is updated for all sheets, you might find [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) useful. Uncomment it from the code above if it's not working.
- Using [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) is not an option here, since it refers to a list of ranges from the same sheet.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback Iamblichus, sorry for the delayed response, as I'm new to Apps Script took me a while to understand and get things running. I modified the script slightly so that the initial selection is selected once all the other sheets are done, and yes flush() was needed to have the desired effect. Without flush, setActiveRange doesn't run within the loop.

Comment: While this works, it may be very resource consuming if it is run on every cell selection. Is there any way we can limit it to just when a row is changed? Also, wouldn't it be much more efficient if we only loop through all sheets when a different sheet is selected? I've seen some code where we are able to detect what the previously selected sheet was. Can we then find the selected row in that sheet and apply it to the newly selected sheet? I have failed to get the selected row of an inactive sheet. Only when a new sheet is selected should it get the row from previous sheet and loop through.

Comment: @Shalin `onSelectionChange` event object doesn't contain information on what the previous row and sheet was, just current one (after selection change) so there's not a direct way to retrieve that. You could store the previous selected row via [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) and compare it to current one when the function is fired, but I'm unsure this is worth it (store and retrieve properties also take time).

Comment: @Shalin If you think this (using `PropertiesService`) could be better for efficiency purposes than loop through all sheets (if you have many sheets, it could probably be), I'd suggest adding that option to my answer. What do you think of that?

Comment: Hi Iamblichus, I had been working on the same and will post code in a separate answer. I provided two solutions, one via menu (which I'm thinking is most resource efficient, just requires user to make 2 clicks) and the other via the ProperiesService so that loops through the sheets only occur once there is a change of sheet.

Comment: @Shalin Is this a completely new solution, or just a variation/addition to the one I provided? If it's the latter, I'd suggest you to edit my answer instead. I'm unsure what your solution via menu is about, I thought you wanted to fire this every time the user changes the row/sheet. Is this just about updating the selected rows when a function is run via Menu?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what Iamblichus' answer, please note [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ETUOskBwrBf93PB_UcM5OlHWDtm7DQU50MOMekDvh-8/edit?usp=sharing) that has 5 sheets Sheets1-5, of which only Sheets1-3 are to be synced.

I worked on two solutions, one via custom menu Sync Sheets, and the other onSelectionChange. Please note code below:

```
    // all sheets
var syncSheet1 = "Sheet1"
var syncSheet2 = "Sheet2"
var syncSheet3 = "Sheet3"
var syncSheet4 = "Sheet4"
var syncSheet5 = "Sheet5"

// array of sync sheets
var syncedSheets = new Array (syncSheet1, syncSheet2, syncSheet3);

function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu("Sync Sheets")
      .addItem("Sync Sheets","scrollAllSheets")
      .addToUi();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu("Goto 10,5")
      .addItem("Goto 10,5","goto10_5")
      .addToUi();

  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  const sheetRowIndex = e.range.getRow();
  prop.setProperty("previousSheet", sheetName);
  prop.setProperty("previousSheetRow", sheetRowIndex);
}

function goto10_5(){
  const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(10,5);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().setActiveRange(row);
  // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function scrollAllSheets() {
  const currentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const rowIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  if (syncedSheets.indexOf(currentSheet) !=  -1){
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(sheet => {
      if (syncedSheets.indexOf(sheet.getSheetName()) != -1){
        const row = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1);
        row.setValue(sheet.getSheetName() + " ;row: " + rowIndex);
        sheet.setActiveRange(row);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(currentSheet).setActiveRange(currentRange);
  } else {
    currentRange.setValue(currentSheet + " is not a synced sheet");
  }
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const previousSheet = prop.getProperty("previousSheet");
  const previousSheetRow = prop.getProperty("previousSheetRow");
  const range = e.range;
  const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  const rowIndex = range.getRow();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  if (sheetName != previousSheet) {
    if (syncedSheets.indexOf(previousSheet) != -1 && syncedSheets.indexOf(sheetName) != -1){
      if (rowIndex != parseInt(previousSheetRow)){
        range.setValue(previousSheet + " row: " + previousSheetRow + "; dif " + rowIndex + " " + sheetName);
        var row = sheet.getRange(parseInt(previousSheetRow),2);
        row.setValue(sheetName);
        sheet.setActiveRange(row);
        // row.activate();
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      } else {
        range.setValue("same " + rowIndex + " " + sheetName);
      }
    } else {
      range.setValue("from not synced sheet: " + previousSheet);
    }
      
  } else {
      range.setValue(a1Notation);
  }
  prop.setProperty("previousSheet", sheetName);
  prop.setProperty("previousSheetRow",rowIndex);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Many thanks for your assistance Iamblichus. I will let the end users chose which solution to implement.

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything relevant to mine, considering your original question (how to automatically scroll different sheets when a new cell is selected), specially firing a function via menu. Using `PropertiesService` to store/retrieve previously selected row/sheets is a nice addition, but not worth a new answer in my opinion. As such, I think it would be more appropriate as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Noted. Been a while since I posted on stackoverflow. Will keep note. In the end I believe firing the function via menu is the most resource friendly solution. Thanks again for your valuable assistance!